# Singleton implementation in C++ not yielding the same class instance when calling the getInstance function

Tags: c++, singleton

```
class Game
{
    public:

        static Game *getGameInstance();

        ~Game();

    private:

        Game();

        static Game *gameContainer;
};
```

Im currently working on a game in C++. When the game launches I call

```
Game *Game::getGameInstance()
{
    if(gameContainer == nullptr)
    {
        gameContainer = new Game;
    }
    return gameContainer;
}
```

which creates a 'new Game' and the game starts as normal. However I now have a use case for calling getGameeInstance from another part of code. The issue is that then I call the getGameInstance function again (Game* game = Game::getGameInstance();) but gameContainer is considered a nullptr and creates a second game instance. Not sure whats really going wrong cause my class seems to be in order

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Does the second call occurs from inside a function called by the Game constructor? Does the Game constructor ever return?

Comment: Without more information of the second call, I think we cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe try to make a small example with your class and test it, if it works or not?

Comment: @macmade you figured it out thanks - my game class never returns as it enters a game loop so when i call the function again the object is still non existent

Comment: @JozefMilenkiewicz The constructor is not supposed to do anything more than to create the object - it's not even a valid, fully constructed object until the constructor has returned. Anything that depends on the object's existence belongs in member functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... which creates a 'new Game' and the game starts as normal

So you are starting the Game from inside the `Game` constructor.
I assume you have some kind of loop inside, meaning your constructor **will never actually return**.

So the assignment of the static instance never occurs.
This is why it's still a `nullptr` on subsequent calls.

You should create the `Game` object, assign the instance, and then start the game:

```
Game *Game::getGameInstance()
{
    if(gameContainer == nullptr)
    {
        gameContainer = new Game;
        game->start();
    }

    return gameContainer;
}
```

Note it’s probably better not to start the game from inside the getInstance method.
Do it from outside instead.

Comment: I wouldn't recomend do it like this. Since function name is *getGameInstance* not *get_and_start_GameInstance*. It would be clear to call *start* from external code.

Comment: Yes, I hesitated to add a note about this... Edited the answer to include this.